# Image is not displaying properly when using live data and retrofit android

Tags: java, android, mvvm, retrofit, android-livedata

All other datas are displaying except image alone not displaying properly.

Below is the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Movies> articleArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    MoviesAdapter newsAdapter;
    RecyclerView rvHeadline;
    MoviesViewModel newsViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rvHeadline = findViewById(R.id.rvNews);

        newsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MoviesViewModel.class);
        newsViewModel.init();
        newsViewModel.getNewsRepository().observe(this, newsResponse -> {
            List<Movies> newsArticles = null;
            if (newsResponse != null) {
                newsArticles = newsResponse.getMovies();
                articleArrayList.addAll(newsArticles);
                newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        setupRecyclerView();
    }

    private void setupRecyclerView() {
        if (newsAdapter == null) {
            newsAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(MainActivity.this, articleArrayList);
            rvHeadline.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            rvHeadline.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
            rvHeadline.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            rvHeadline.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
        } else {
            newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}


public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MoviesViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Movies> articles;

    public MoviesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Movies> articles) {
        this.context = context;
        this.articles = articles;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MoviesAdapter.MoviesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.movies_item, parent, false);
        return new MoviesViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MoviesAdapter.MoviesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvName.setText(articles.get(position).getTitle()); //this is working
        holder.tvDesCription.setText(articles.get(position).getDirector());
        String url = articles.get(position).getPoster();
        if(url!=null) {
           /* Glide.with(context) //passing context
                    .load(url) //passing your url to load image.
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .placeholder(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)) //this would be your default image (like default profile or logo etc). it would be loaded at initial time and it will replace with your loaded image once glide successfully load image using url.
                    .centerCrop()//this method help to fit image into center of your ImageView
                    .into(holder.ivNews);*/ //pass imageView reference to appear the image.*/
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(url)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .into(holder.ivNews);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return articles.size();
    }

    public class MoviesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvName;
        TextView tvDesCription;
        ImageView ivNews;

        public MoviesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            tvDesCription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDesCription);
            ivNews = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivNews);

        }
    }
}
```

I am not able to figure out where exactly I am doing the mistake. Because image from response is displaying only for certain table whereas others it's duplicating by displaying the same images or it's not displaying too. I used Glide and picasso too but still the image is not displaying from response for some list.

Comment: You need add `else`-statement for  `if(url!=null) {` otherwise the holder will have legacy data

Answer (score 0):

in adapter use if and else condition both at that time.. 
just add this code into your project :

```
 if(url!=null){
        Picasso.get()
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .into(holder.ivNews);
    } else {
        Picasso.get()
                .load(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .into(holder.ivNews);
    }
```